# Can't send Email from my android Application

Tags: android, email

[image]Hi

I have used the following tutorial to send email from my application :

http://coderzheaven.com/2011/05/send-email-from-and-android-application-programatically/

But I am getting the following error when I try to do so:

"No application can perform this action"

I have attached the Snapshot of emulator below. Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*`If you are using an emulator, you’ll need to configure the email client. If the email client is not configured, it will not respond to the Intent we’ll be discussing. If you want to see the chooser in action, you’ll need to configure a device using multiple messaging applications, such as the Gmail application and the Email application.`*

First you have to configure your email client.

For example add gmail account to emulator as

```
Settings > Accounts & Sync > Add Account > Google
```

after adding account, run your code.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not provide API to send Email directly, you have to call the existing Email client to send Email.

Answer (score 0):

you must configure email client on emulator (or device if you use it) with an account, smtp e pop3 host.